# Make all longtables in a document full page width

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a set of documents with lots of tables using the `longtable` package. I am looking for a way to force all tables full page width. I know that this can be done by setting this in the preambles:

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
```

and then adding `\extracolsep{\fill}` to each table.

However is there a way to achieve the same effect without modifying each individual table? Perhaps by using `renewenvironment` to redefine `longtable` so that `\extracolsep{\fill}` is always used?

Comment: not really, you'd have to patch `LT@array` to modify the definition of `\LT@bchunk` to use fill rather than 0pt when setting `\tabskip`.  simpler just to use `\newcolumtype{Z}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}` then use `Z` at the start of the longtable  preamble argument (although forcing columns apart makes the table harder to read for no real gain)

Comment: The problem is that I have no direct control over the column definitions (these documents are generated by an external tool). Any other option ?

Comment: as I say my preferred option is not to do it and let the column separation be natural width, makes for easier reading, but if that isn't an option, use a patch command (eg from etoolbox) and change `\tabskip\z@` to `\tabskip\fill` in `\LT@array`

Comment: Thank you. Although I'll have to study that a bit before I understand your suggestion (I'm new to Latex :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,etoolbox}

\begin{document}

Nice
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\textbf{heading a}&\textbf{heading b}\\
1&2\\3&4\\5&6\\1&2\\3&4\\5&6
\end{longtable}

Horrible
{\setlength\LTleft{0pt}\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc@{}}
\textbf{heading a}&\textbf{heading b}\\
1&2\\3&4\\5&6\\1&2\\3&4\\5&6
\end{longtable}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\LT@array{\tabskip\z@}{\tabskip\fill}{\typeout{OK}}{\typeout{BAD}}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\makeatletter

Automatically Horrible
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\textbf{heading a}&\textbf{heading b}\\
1&2\\3&4\\5&6\\1&2\\3&4\\5&6
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very illustrative :)