# Text alignment in tabularx header only works for the first column

Tags: tabularx

```
 \begin{tabularx}{.96\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c| }
 \hline
   \textbf{Xxx1} & 
   \textbf{Xxx2} & 
   \textbf{Xxx3} \\ 
 \hline
   & & \\
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}
```

Why Xxx1 is centered (correctly) and Xxx2 and Xxx3 are right aligned (incorrectly)?

Comment: it is hard to know what you have as you have not made your example complete, so we can not run it, but the table is in error, a `tabularx` should always have an `X` column, or use `tabular` instead.

Comment: it is best not to use `|` and `\extracolsep` in the same table as the extra space always goes to the right of the rule.

Comment: Well, may be I'm going in the wrong way. I just want the table to use all the width. Is there a better approach?

Comment: using the full width should be a non-aim, but  if you want to do it with `ccc` use the standard `tabular*` rather than `tabularx`  and generally the advice is to avoid vertical rules.

Comment: see this for methods on making the table wide http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245770/make-all-longtables-in-a-document-full-page-width/245786#245786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\centering

space is added after the rules;

 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|@{}}
 \hline
   \textbf{Xxx1} & 
   \textbf{Xxx2} & 
   \textbf{Xxx3} \\ 
 \hline
   & & \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular*}

\bigskip
without rules:

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc@{}}
 \hline
   \textbf{Xxx1} & 
   \textbf{Xxx2} & 
   \textbf{Xxx3} \\ 
 \hline
   & & \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular*}

\bigskip
not stretched (much more readable)

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 \hline
   \textbf{Xxx1} & 
   \textbf{Xxx2} & 
   \textbf{Xxx3} \\ 
 \hline
   & & \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

\bigskip tabularx

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
|*3{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}@{}}
 \hline
   \textbf{Xxx1} & 
   \textbf{Xxx2} & 
   \textbf{Xxx3} \\ 
 \hline
   & & \\
 \hline
 \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to auto adjust column width in respect to the text size (i.e. Xxx3 should be smaller then Xxxxxxxxxxxx4)?

Comment: @oqrxke yes that is what latex does, (for all versions except tabularx) .  A `c` column is set according to content, `p` or `X` columns fix a width then the content is wrapped to that length.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I just wonder if there is anyway in LaTeX to do the last table BUT without the first and the last vertical lines!

Comment: @doctorate yes of course just take them out of the preamble so `*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X`